# compress with tar, tar : Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, compression, tar

I'm trying to compress files, but I use other user

Say there are two user here, user 1 "test1" and user 2 "test2"

I logged in as user 2 "test2"

Then, I wanted to compress files in the user directory "test1"

```
"/Home/test1/Downloads/repos/"
```

I've run the command

```
$ Tar -zcvf $HOME/backup_file.tar.gz /home/test1/Downloads/repos/
```

When there is an error compress process

```
tar : Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

I've tried the way of the link below, but still error

[tar Exiting with failure status due to previous errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58144/tar-exiting-with-failure-status-due-to-previous-errors)

Assistance and solutions is greatly appreciated

Comment: Can test2 read the Downloads/repos/ directory of  test1 at all?

Comment: user "test2" can view the contents of the "/home/test1/Downloads/repos/"

Comment: Are all sub directories readable as well? Does 'find /home/test1/Downloads/repos/ > /dev/null' show any output at all?

Comment: Can use "sudo" to have a try.

Answer (score 1):

The original folder compressed was created by the **root** authority, and your implementation of the **tar** maybe no **sudo**